# How do I sort data by date (json)

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb

I want to sort json data by date , Actual data hava 1 ~ 31
example data:

```
{
  Detail: { '60': 100, '68': 20 },
  Time: 2020-01-02T07:08:41.059Z,
  No: 'aaa'
},
{
  Detail: { '60': 300, '68': 20 },
  Time: 2020-01-02T09:10:21.059Z,
  No: 'bbb'
},
{
  Detail: { '60': 10 },
  Time: 2020-01-11T07:08:45.521Z,
  No: 'ccc'
}
```

How do I sort by Date like this :

```
{
  "2":{
     "aaa": { '60': 100, '68': 20 }
     "bbb": { '60': 300, '68': 20 }
   }
  "11":{
     "ccc": { '60': 100 },
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following aggregation does that. Assuming that the `Time` field of type `Date`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { day: { $dayOfMonth: "$Time" } }, 
          data:{ $push: { k: "$No", v: "$Detail" } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $sort: { "_id.day": 1 } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }, 
          day: "$_id.day" 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: {
          _id: null, 
          data: { $push: { k: { $toString: "$_id.day" }, v: "$data" } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: {
           _id: 0, 
           data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } 
  }
] ).pretty()
```